# How To Use Update Function In Repeater Control Dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, edit, insert-update

i have 1 repeater and **bind subjectid and subjectname** from **Assign_Subjects** table...and put **1 textbox** template to insert marks obtained in each subjects **@btnInsert_Click** event and i already wrote my insertion code as below and it works fine...and **result** table in which i want to insert marks along with subjects...

> I want to update the marks i.e inserted (in textbox - MarksObtained column) within repeater control...i used button as btnUpdate for edit textboxes....

**.aspx** page

```
<div>
 <table border="0" width="600px" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" style="border: 1px solid maroon;">
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <tr bgcolor="maroon">
                        <th>
                            Subject_Id
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Subject_Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Fill_Marks
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubjectId" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("Subject_Id")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubjectName" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("Subject_Name")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMarks" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </table>
        <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" runat="server" OnClick="btnInsert_Click" Text="Insert" />
        **<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" Text="Insert" />**
    </div>
```

**code behind - c#**

```
   protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      foreach (RepeaterItem repeaterItem in Repeater1.Items)
      {
          string subjectId = (repeaterItem.FindControl("txtSubjectId") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
          string subjectName = (repeaterItem.FindControl("txtSubjectName") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
          string marks = (repeaterItem.FindControl("txtMarks") as TextBox).Text.Trim();

          this.SaveData(subjectId, subjectName, marks);
      }
  }

 private void SaveData(string subjectId, string subjectName, string marks)
        {
            cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnect"].ConnectionString);
            cn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into result(id,name,marks) values('"+subjectId+"','"+subjectName+"','"+marks+"')", cn);

            Repeater1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //Display a popup which indicates that the record was successfully inserted

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Script", "alert('Successfuly Inserted. !!');", true);

            cn.Close();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            cmd.Connection.Dispose();
        }
```

Insert into **result** table

```
id     varchar(20)
name   varchar(20)
marks  varchar(20)
```

**Now question is how can i update through repeaters ???** explained with code more appriciated... thanks

Comment: Firstly you should use Parameters for building your SqlCommand otherwise you leave yourself open to SQL injection attacks. Second - what is the exact error you get?

Comment: I'm confused on what you're trying to accomplish.  You have a repeater that I assume you populate with data.  Then when you click Insert it loops through each item in the repeater and does an INSERT into your database?  I think instead you probably mean to put text boxes below the repeater to add a new item to the list?

Comment: kevin main - i updated my question...you can see it...

Comment: Michael - i have 1 repeater and bind subjectid and subjectname from **Assign_Subjects** table...and puted 1 textbox template to insert marks obtained in each subjects **@btnInsert_Click** event and i already wrote my insertion code as above...and **result** table in which i want to insert marks along with subjects...

Comment: After you do the insert you are rebinding the repeater which means the data in the Repeater1.Items collection changes and hence the error. Remove the binding in your SaveData() method.

Comment: hey kevin Main - thanks... but problem is in **txtMarks it takes NULL** vales means cant read data from repeater...what should i have to do ?

Comment: Only bind the repeater in PageLoad if not postback that should solve it

Comment: its disable when we run application...please give me a sample code...so that i studied well it

Comment: thanks Main - its solved successfully. !! cheears... can you give me a sample code for Update function ???

Answer (score 0):

your buttons inside repeater should look like this.....

```
 <td>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSave" runat="server"  
         ImageUrl="~/images/save.png" ToolTip="click to save record"  
         CommandName="SaveData" 
         OnClientClick="return confirm('Conform message before  saving')" />
</td>
```

then to capture the events generated by repeater control use  Repeater's ItemCommand event

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
   // note that this is the command we assign to save button. 
   // we use it here to capture which button was clicked.
    if (e.CommandName == "SaveData")
    {
        TextBox txtFirstName = e.Item.FindControl("txtFirstName") as TextBox;
        string fname= txtFirstName.Text;

       // do somethig with your date here..

    }
}
```